# Root Page is not coming after successful auto persistence login in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, angular2-routing, angular2-template, ionic3

I'm using ionic 3 and want to auto login using storage plugin for storing login details. I'm able to print login data from storage but after successful login rootPage, for me its homePage is not coming. I'm getting some error like :-

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'rootPage' of undefined**

Code is written below :-

```
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = LoginPage;

  if (status) {
            var _dataObj = JSON.parse(data);            
            rest.setAuthToken(_dataObj.userId, _dataObj.authToken);
            this.rootPage = LoginPage;                    
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add all the relevant code? where does that `status` variable comes from? Is it inside of another function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the this value to a variable and than use that.

```
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = LoginPage;
   let self = this;
  if (status) {
            var _dataObj = JSON.parse(data);            
            rest.setAuthToken(_dataObj.userId, _dataObj.authToken);
            self.rootPage = LoginPage;                    
  }
}
```